# Confused about the verb "relax" which means "make or become less tense or anxious"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The word "*relax*" means "*make or become less tense or anxious*." [Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relax)

If you see these 2 simple sentences:

> (1) *I relax*.  (2) *I am relaxed*.

Does (1) mean "*I become less less tense or anxious*"?

Does (2) mean "*someone / something makes me less tense or anxious*"?

Comment: I would have thought (2) might suggest "I am not tense or anxious"

Answer (score 3):

1) It could do, but except in a special context it's more likely to mean another sense of the verb *relax*:"To cease or lessen one's efforts; to rest; to seek or take recreation." (Sense 5b in the OED).

2) No. *Relaxed* can be the past participle of *relax*, so verb forms including it are possible, eg *I had relaxed my grip*. But in modern English, this form is never used with parts of *be*, so in *I am relaxed* it must be an adjective, not a verb, meaning "Leisurely, at ease; free from tension, anxiety, or stress." (meaning 3 of *relaxed* in the OED). It is not a passive, so there is no implication of an agent reducing my tension or stress. (It does not rule out there being an external agent, but it does not imply one either).